# No targets specified and no makefile found in Nominatim installation

Tags: ubuntu, makefile

I'm trying to setting up my own OpenStreetMap server and i followed the official tutorial in Wikipedia and one other tutorial. First i clone Nominatim from GIT and i build it by taping :

```
cd Nominatim/
cd module/
sudo make
cd ..
cd nominatim/
sudo ./autogen.sh
sudo ./configure
```

and everything is fine till now. but when i tape `sudo make` after that i got this :

```
make: **** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.
```

how do i fix this ? thanks in advance

Comment: You do not want `sudo` on `make`, `autogen.sh` *or* `configure`. You **only** want it (if necessary) on `make install`. The permissions of many files in your current source directory will now be incorrect (root owned, etc.). Did the `configure` step finish correctly? That error (at this point in an autotool-ed project) usually means it didn't.

Comment: well i got this error and i skipped saying that it can't be a real problem : "checking for postgreSQL libraries...configure : error : postgresql server development library not found" is that the real problem ??

Comment: If that caused `configure` to exit with an error instead of completing successfully then yes that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in postgresql, so after installing:

- postgresql-server-dev-9.3
- libpgtcl-dev

the problem is solved. Thank You.